# All actions denied on MS SQL Server on Go Daddy Hosting

Tags: sql-server, database, hosting

i have a website hosted on GoDaddy and I need to create a database for it. So headed to the `Databases` section and created a MS SQL Database then on my local pc I tried to access the database via SQL Server Management studio, I was able to login to the database but I cannot make any operations. I get `it does not exist or you do not have permission.` So deciced to go the `Security` tab, then `Login` and tried to change my username that I'm using to systemadmin role but I also got `Cannot alter the server role 'sysadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.` What could be the problem? There are no other accounts on it. The default `sa` account is disbaled and I can't enable it coz it will prompt no permissions etc.

I don't understand it. Why GoDaddy allows me to create a database but with no permissions or rather I cannot alter it. Anyone facing the same issue? Thanks

Comment: You cant use sysadmin on shared hosting. You need to manage your database via your Control panel. You can connect via webadmin or remotely to the server using your credentials that you created on control panel. For more information, please just contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite clear. You cannot set yourself as an SA. This would be a great security breach!

You need to add a Login in your database for your account. I think you headed to the server logins. The server login seem to be ok, as you already said. You can connect to the server itself. You need to add a login or a loginmapping to your server login inside your database.

I don't know the backend of goDaddy, but I'm pretty sure that you have some credentials provided after creating your database.

Comment: Can you guide me or give me idea what to do next? I noticed something, on go daddy I created another user, then when I checked on the SQL Management Studio that user in only Login Type. So basically every user that I create from godaddy control panel will be for Login only. That's why I was able to login I guess. But creating database from sql management studio or any other operations I can't

Comment: You can try to run the following in your master database:
`SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'yourDatabase'`. This should give you an output if the database you think you've created already exists. Otherwise you can open `VIEW > Template Explorer` in your Management Studio. This will popup the template browser. After that, you'll be able to browse all templates. Open Database in the browser and double click `CREATE DATABASE`. This will help you creating a database if your not so experienced. :-)

Comment: By the way, you can take a look in the docs here too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx